# Pandas Sum DataFrame Columns of various types

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, tostring

I am trying to concatenate two columns of a Pandas DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [2, 1, 3, 4], 'B': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
```

(Formatted):

```
   A  B
0  2  a
1  1  b
2  3  c
3  4  d
```

Trying `sum([df[column] for column in df])` doesn't work, obviously because you can't map adding integers (column `A`) to strings (columns `B`).

So I added the lines:

```
for column in df1:
    df1[column] = df1[column].apply(str)
```

And just to make sure the string conversions were working properly, I added the following statement:

```
print([df[column].apply(type) for column in df])
```

Which produces

```
In : print([df[column].apply(type) for column in df])

Out:
[0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: A, dtype: object, 0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
3    <class 'str'>
Name: B, dtype: object]
```

But *still*, when I run `sum([df[column] for column in df])` I get the error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'`.

What is going on?

Comment: By "Concatenate" I mean string concatenate the columns to generate a Series of strings

Comment: The expected output should be a Pandas Series with elements '2a', '1b', '3c', '4d'. I'm not worried about the column header.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC, you can concatenate your columns like this:

```
df.astype(str).sum(axis=1)

0    2a
1    1b
2    3c
3    4d
dtype: object
```

This turns all columns to type `str` (`df.astype(str)`) and then uses `sum` to concatenate row-wise (`axis=1`)

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
In [99]: df.A.astype(str) + df.B
Out[99]:
0    2a
1    1b
2    3c
3    4d
dtype: object
```

Alternative, with `apply`, which could be slow.

```
In [106]: df.apply(lambda x: '{A}{B}'.format(**x), axis=1)
Out[106]:
0    2a
1    1b
2    3c
3    4d
dtype: object
```

[@JonClements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51750436/pandas-sum-dataframe-columns-of-various-types/51750535?noredirect=1#comment90461323_51750535) has a nice alternative with `format_map`

```
In [124]: df.apply('{A}{B}'.format_map, axis=1)
Out[124]:
0    2a
1    1b
2    3c
3    4d
dtype: object
```

Comment: I like this, but when I generalize your solution to `s = sum([df[column].astype(str) for column in df])`, why am I getting the unsupported type exception again?

Comment: @Zero you can be a little cheeky on `lambda x: '{A}{B}'.format(**x)` and make it `'{A}{B}'.format_map` there... (seems about 10% faster avoiding the lambda and dict-unpacking)

Comment: @JonClements -- oh my, wasn't in aware of `format_map`, pretty cool, thanks.

Comment: Seriously, I've written that `lambda` before.  `lambda kw: '{A}{B}'.format(**kw)`

Answer (score 2):

If you're interested in performance, use `f-strings` and a list comprehension.

```
pd.Series([f'{i}{j}' for i,j in zip(df.A, df.B)])

0    2a
1    1b
2    3c
3    4d
dtype: object
```

Due to pandas handling strings inefficiently, this will be a very fast option comparatively.

Comment: Or even more time saved using `df.A.values` and `df.B.values`